# NativeScript Service exited due to Trace/BPT trap: 5

Tags: nativescript

I’m trying to run the [Groceries app](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-1#14-running-your-app) for the first time, and it seems to be exiting with the system.log message below. Can anyone help?

I've tried both the angular-start and master branch. Same error.

tns 2.2.1
Simulator Version 10.0 (SimulatorApp-700.5.3 
Xcode Version 8.0 (8A218a)

`Sep 13 19:05:44 CHRISTOPHERs-MacBook-Pro com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.499CBAD2-C487-495B-A343-DFB9A16D127D.launchd_sim[25503] (UIKitApplication:org.nativescript.groceries[0x5f5][25953]): Service exited due to Trace/BPT trap: 5`

Answer (score 0):

Same thing for me since upgrading to ios 10, xcode 8.  Anyway, I went to Simulator > Hardware > Device > Manage Devices.  Then I installed ios 9 and it works again. Need to figure out problem with 10, but at least in 9 I got some error messages that helped me get it up again.

Answer (score 0):

There is some discussion here:
https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/issues/501

One suggestion is to add this to the www/index.html file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src gap://ready file://* *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

I have a Cordova/Ionic app that runs fine on iOS 8 and 9 and throws the same error (also uses Angular).

Maybe something else security related is blocking something?
Please share if you find a solution.